# VSCode, Python3.7: pylint no-member error with custom decorated class

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have recently moved an instance method out of its class definition and put is as a global function (in example: deco_function) to be able to use it in different classes again. See the following code for detailed explanation and bug reproduction:

```
def deco_function(cls):
    
    def inner_fct(self):
        print('do something')

    cls.deco_function = inner_fct
    return cls

@deco_function
class Something:

    def __init__(self):
        print('init')
        self.deco_function()
        print('done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Something()
```

The code runs completely fine, printing

```
init
do something
done
```

however, VSCode underlines `self.deco_function()` red, with pylint stating, that Instance 'Something' has no 'deco_function' member.

Is there a way around, preventing pylint from marking this or making VSCode recognize deco_function as an Instance member?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a PyLint plugin to tell which class members are runtime generated

Create a file `pylint_decorator.py` somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH`

```python
import astroid
from astroid import MANAGER

def register(linter):
  # Needed for registering the plugin.
  pass

def transform(cls):
  if not cls.decorators: return
  if any(map(lambda x: x.name == 'deco_function', cls.decorators.nodes)):
    extension_module = astroid.parse("""
def deco_function(self):
  pass
""")
    for name, objs in extension_module.locals.items():
      cls.locals[name] = objs

MANAGER.register_transform(astroid.ClassDef, transform)
```

then configure VSC with the following setting

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_decorator"]
```

This only works if you use the `@deco_function` syntax.

If you call the decorator function PyLint will not see the use of the decorator

```python
# this use will not be catched by the plugin
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        print('init')
        self.deco_function()
        print('done')
Something = deco_function(Something)
```

Comment: There seems to be another flaw: ```<class 'UnboundLocalError'>: local variable 'extension_module' referenced before assignmentpylint(astroid-error)``` Any idea? That error appears now in any module I open...

Comment: I found that astroid also keeps track of the decorators, so no need to name the explicit classes

Comment: what do you see if you use the command `pylint -E --load-plugins pylint-decorator deco_test.py`. Is your indentation in the plugin identical to the code provided?

Comment: I guess, I had the indentation inside the ```astroid.parse()``` method wrong. Doesn't show the error anymore, but pylint seems to have gotten way more sensitive... :D lots of remarks.

Comment: The explicit command raises an ```ImportError : No module named 'pylint_decorator'```though. That is strange, as it seems to work anyway.

Comment: @Robert I just saw I made a small typo, the file should be called `pylint_decorator.py` and it should be on your `PYTHONPATH`, I tested it with `set PYTHONPATH=.` and putting the plugin in the current working directory. You can also set the arguments for pylint in a `.pylint.rc` file but the docs are not very clear what to write in there, and there are multiple places you can put this file (see the doc). What type of remarks do you get?

Comment: I had noticed the typo, but thanks for pointing it out. I also figured out the ImportError: Anaconda doesn't share the PYTHONPATH, that pylint uses (the system-path), so pylint indeed did not find the module. Now the output is empty, which is, what you were aiming for, right?!

Comment: @Robert Instead of Anaconda you can use the `venv` module of Python. I don't know if Anaconda does additional things

Comment: As of 2022, it seems `lambda x: x.name` should be `lambda x: x.attrname`